# Trigonometry problem $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha)$

Tags: trigonometry

I stucked with one problem in trigonometry.
Here is the problem:

Determine

$$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha\Big),$$ if 
$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\Big) = -\frac{15}{17},$$ 
where
$$\alpha \in \Big[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\Big].$$

From where to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expand using $\cos(a+b)$ formula
$$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\Big)=\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}\Big)\cos(\alpha)-\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}\Big)\sin(\alpha),$$
or equivalently
$$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\Big)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(\alpha)-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Big(\cos(\alpha)-\sin(\alpha)\Big).$$
Now
$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)=\cos(x).$$
The justification of the above can be seen by using the expansion of $\sin(a-b)$
$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)=\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)=\cos(x),$$
since $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0.$
So now
$$\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\Big)=\cos(\alpha)=-\frac{15}{17}.$$
Then, using $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$, we have
$$\sin^2(\alpha)=1-\frac{225}{289}=\frac{64}{289} \Rightarrow \sin(\alpha)=\pm\frac{8}{17},$$
but we only take the positive solution. Finally $$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\Big)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Big(\cos(\alpha)-\sin(\alpha)\Big)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Big(-\frac{15}{17}-\frac{8}{17}\Big)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Big(-\frac{23}{17}\Big)=-\frac{23\sqrt{2}}{34}.$$

Comment: Why is $sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - x) = cos(x)$ ?

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint
We know that sin((pi/2)-a)=cosa
Also we know that cos(a+b)=cosa •cosb -sina •sinb.
And sin^2 (x) +cos^2(x)= 1
Knowing all these is pretty easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

By **trigonometric identities**:

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)=\cos \alpha=-\frac{15}{17}$$

$$\sin^2 \alpha+\cos^2 \alpha =1, \quad \alpha \in \Big[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\Big].\implies\sin \alpha=\frac{8}{17}$$

> **Thus**
>
> $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\right)=\cos \frac{\pi}{4} \cos \alpha-\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \sin \alpha=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\cos \alpha-\sin \alpha\right)=-\frac{23\sqrt{2}}{34}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos\alpha=\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\Big) = -\frac{15}{17}\\
\sin\alpha=\frac8{17} \quad \text{ as }\alpha \in \Big[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\Big].$$

\begin{align}
& \cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha\Big) \\
=& \cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \cos\alpha-\sin\Big(\frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \sin\alpha \\
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(-\frac{15}{17}-\frac8{17}) \\
=& -\frac{23}{17\sqrt2}
\end{align}

Comment: I think that $sin\alpha$ should be $\frac{-2}{17}$ not $\frac{8}{17}$ ?!?

Comment: Observe that $8,15,17$ is the 2nd smallest Pythagoras triple.